# Why does this Eloquent query not get the expected results?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

For practice, I am making a web app in Laravel for a fictional company that sells training courses. I have a table for Courses, Venues, and Instances. An Instance defines the date and venue for a particular course. For example, Course A may run in New York on 2020-06-05, London on 2020-07-02, etc etc.

I have defined the relationships like this:

```
class Instance extends Model
{
    public function courses(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
    }

    public function venues(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Venue::class);
    }

}
```

```
class Course extends Model
{
    public function instances(){
        return $this->hasMany(Instance::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Venue extends Model
{
    public function instances(){
        return $this->hasMany(Instance::class);
    }
}
```

The `id` of the courses and venues table are foreign keys in the instance table.

I want to get all the instances associated with a given course, and pull in the venue for each one too, so I try the following query in Tinker:

`$instance = App\Instance::with('venues')->where('course_id','=',1)->get()`

This gives me the following output:

```
         course_id: 1,
         venue_id: 2,
         date: "2020-11-04",
         length: 0,
         cost: 635.0,
         created_at: "2020-05-26 13:35:06",
         updated_at: "2020-05-26 13:35:06",
         venues: null,
```

As you can see, `venues` is null. My question is... why?

Comment: can you show your relationships code too ?

Comment: Could you share the relationship you specified in the model?

Comment: `public function venues(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Venue::class, 'venue_id');
    }` try this code inside your Instance model

Comment: @AkhtarMunir that works, thank you! Why was that necessary though?

Comment: You welcome, sometimes we make foreign_keys different, so then we need to manually tell the eloquent to use our default key.

Comment: I see. Well, feel free to add it as an answer and I will gladly accept!

Comment: The issue is the pluralised name you have given to the function.  Laravel under the hood will look at the function name and work out the foreign key it should try to use.  So in your case its looking for 'venues_id', because a 'belongs_to' relationship should return a single record the function name should be venue(), then Laravel will look for 'venue_id'.  Of course you can override the foreign key as you have but just explaining why it didnt work.

Comment: Thanks @ColinMD. As an experiment I changed venues() to venue() in the Instance model and it threw an error `"Call to undefined relationship [venues] on model [App\\Instance]."`

Comment: Its probably because of this line, will need changing to venue also  App\Instance::with('venues')

Comment: anywhere you did call venues will need to be changed to venue

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the pluralised name you have given to the function.

Laravel under the hood will look at the function name and work out the foreign key it should try to use. So in your case its looking for 'venues_id', because a 'belongs_to' relationship should return a single record the function name should be venue(), then Laravel will look for 'venue_id'.

Of course you can override the foreign key as you have but just explaining why it didnt work.